# What is the iterative Jacobi method for the linear system $Ax = b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

In order to solve the linear system $Ax = b$, we consider the following iterative method:
$$x_{1, k+1} = \frac{1}{4} (-x_{1, k} -x_{2, k} +x_{3, k} + 3)$$
$$x_{2, k+1} = \frac{1}{6} (2x_{1, k} +x_{2, k} -x_{3, k} + 3)$$
$$x_{3, k+1} = \frac{1}{4} (-x_{1, k} +x_{2, k} +x_{3, k} + 1)$$

Question is, what are the iterative equations for the Jacobi method for the initial linear system? Does said Jacobi method converge?

My work so far has revolved around the given iterative method. I found its C-matrix and proved it converges, since $\|C\|_{\infty} < 1$. But I can't figure out how that helps me when it comes to the Jacobi method.

Comment: You should write down the expressions for $A$, $b$ and $C$. There are a few choices when it comes to the definition of $C$ and while one is more likely than the others you are much more likely to get help when there is no doubt.

Comment: This is the exact statement of the question. There are no expressions for $A$ or $b$.

$C$ on the other hand can be calculated, it's the matrix of the coefficients of $x_{i, k}$ and boils down to
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} \\
-\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So you have $x = Cx + f$ for some $C$ that you have identified. Can you identify $f$ and compute $x$? How would you normally transition from $Ax=b$ to Jacobi's method?

Answer (score 0):

In Jacobi's method, each equation $i$ is of the form
$$x_i = \frac{1}{a_{ii}}\left(b_i - \sum_{j\ne i} a_{ij} x_j\right)$$

So, you get Jacobi's iteration simply by isolating $x_i$ in the LHS on each equation. In this case you get
$$
\begin{cases}
x_{1,k+1} = \frac 15 (-x_{2,k}+x_{3,k}+3)\\
x_{2,k+1} = \frac 15 (2 x_{1,k} - x_{3,k} +3)\\
x_{3,k+1} = \frac 13 (-x_{1,k}+x_{2,k}+1)
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: I still don't get how you ended up with those coefficients for Jacobi's iteration.